VBA timer stops running when using another Excel workbook
I'm using the following VBA script for a countdown timer in Excel. It works well, except that the timer stops running when I switch to another Excel workbook - is there a way to keep it running in the background while I use another Excel file?
Option Explicit
Global interval As Date

Sub timer()
   interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
   If Range("I8").Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
   Range("I8") = Range("I8") - TimeValue("00:00:01")
   Application.OnTime interval, "timer"
End Sub

Sub reset()
   Range("I8") = TimeValue("00:01:30")
End Sub

Sub stop_timer()
   Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=interval, Procedure:="timer", Schedule:=False
End Sub


Is VBA actually stopping, or is some visual indicator just no longer updating? Does this happen when you change focus to a different application that is not Excel? When you come back to the application, does the timer "jump" to a current time?

what does this mean exactly? ... switch to another Excel workbook

try referring to I8 by its full name workbook.worksheet.range

To clarify, the timer stops running when I click in another Excel file. However, the timer still runs successfully when I click in another non-Excel application.

Workbooks().Worksheets().Range() worked - thank you!
